# Google cloud logging API and BigQuery Sink - both duplicate and missing log entries

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, winston, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a cloud function in GCP written in Node.js that before it sends a Pub/Sub message writes a log entry to stack driver using Winston. Logs are then exported to BigQuery (using a standard Sink).

Cloud function is triggered from DataFlow -> Pub/Sub topic at a rather high rate i.e. ~500 cloud function invocations/second with ~1000+ instances running at the same time.

Issue is that when looking in BigQuery I have both duplicate entries (exact the same log entry is logged twice) and I also am missing log entries from executions I know ran fine.

I know there is a logging threshold / project of 1K entries/second but I am not hitting that, still I have issues. I get the feeling that either Winston and/or the Sink is the root-problem.

Anyone recognize this or have an solution?

Thx,
CJ